# What is the best way to tidy a matrix in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a best practice means of "tidying" a matrix/array? By "tidy" in this context I mean

- one row per element of the matrix
- one column per dimension. the elements of these columns give you the "coordinates" of the matrix element which is stored on that row

I have an example here for a 2d matrix, but ideally this would work with an array also (This example works for `mm <- array(1:18, c(3,3,3))`, but I thought that would be too much to paste in here)

```r
mm <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
mm
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    4    7
#> [2,]    2    5    8
#> [3,]    3    6    9
inds <- which(mm > -Inf, arr.ind = TRUE)
cbind(inds, value = mm[inds])
#>       row col value
#>  [1,]   1   1     1
#>  [2,]   2   1     2
#>  [3,]   3   1     3
#>  [4,]   1   2     4
#>  [5,]   2   2     5
#>  [6,]   3   2     6
#>  [7,]   1   3     7
#>  [8,]   2   3     8
#>  [9,]   3   3     9
```

Comment: Best in what sense? And what kind of matrices? A representation like you suggest is more space-efficient for sparse matrices, but not for dense ones - the original form outperforms there.

Comment: If you want a sparse representation of a matrix, use the Matrix package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**as.data.frame.table** One way to convert from wide to long is the following.  See `?as.data.frame.table` for more information. No packages are used.

```
mm <- matrix(1:9, 3)
long <- as.data.frame.table(mm)
```

The code gives this data.frame:

```
> long
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    A    A    1
2    B    A    2
3    C    A    3
4    A    B    4
5    B    B    5
6    C    B    6
7    A    C    7
8    B    C    8
9    C    C    9
```

**numbers**

If you prefer row and column numbers:

```
long[1:2] <- lapply(long[1:2], as.numeric)
```

giving:

```
> long
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    1    1    1
2    2    1    2
3    3    1    3
4    1    2    4
5    2    2    5
6    3    2    6
7    1    3    7
8    2    3    8
9    3    3    9
```

**names** Note that above it used A, B, C, ... because there were no row or column names.  They would have been used if present. That is, had there been row and column names and dimension names the output would look like this:

```
mm2 <- array(1:9, c(3, 3), dimnames = list(A = c("a", "b", "c"), B = c("x", "y", "z")))
as.data.frame.table(mm2, responseName = "Val")
```

giving:

```
  A B Val
1 a x   1
2 b x   2
3 c x   3
4 a y   4
5 b y   5
6 c y   6
7 a z   7
8 b z   8
9 c z   9
```

**3d**

Here is a 3d example:

```
as.data.frame.table(array(1:8, c(2,2,2)))
```

giving:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Freq
1    A    A    A    1
2    B    A    A    2
3    A    B    A    3
4    B    B    A    4
5    A    A    B    5
6    B    A    B    6
7    A    B    B    7
8    B    B    B    8
```

**2d only** For 2d one can alternately use `row` and `col`:

```
sapply(list(row(mm), col(mm), mm), c)
```

or

```
cbind(c(row(mm)), c(col(mm)), c(mm))
```

Either of these give this matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    1    2
 [3,]    3    1    3
 [4,]    1    2    4
 [5,]    2    2    5
 [6,]    3    2    6
 [7,]    1    3    7
 [8,]    2    3    8
 [9,]    3    3    9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use `arrayInd` together with `cbind` like this.

```
# a 3 X 3 X 2 array
mm <- array(1:18, dim=c(3,3,2))
```

Similar to your code, but with the more natural `arrayInd` function, we have

```
# get array in desired format
myMat <- cbind(c(mm), arrayInd(seq_along(mm), .dim=dim(mm)))

# add column names
colnames(myMat) <- c("values", letters[24:26])
```

which returns

```
myMat
      values x y z
 [1,]      1 1 1 1
 [2,]      2 2 1 1
 [3,]      3 3 1 1
 [4,]      4 1 2 1
 [5,]      5 2 2 1
 [6,]      6 3 2 1
 [7,]      7 1 3 1
 [8,]      8 2 3 1
 [9,]      9 3 3 1
[10,]     10 1 1 2
[11,]     11 2 1 2
[12,]     12 3 1 2
[13,]     13 1 2 2
[14,]     14 2 2 2
[15,]     15 3 2 2
[16,]     16 1 3 2
[17,]     17 2 3 2
[18,]     18 3 3 2
```